# esp8266 android connection via telnet

Tags: java, android, multithreading, telnet, arduino-esp8266

Ive been trying from a very long time to send a string from android app to esp8266 through Telnet. I wish to see the output on serial monitor of arduino IDE.I have used the code from [send string to esp8266 via android using telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708711/send-string-to-esp8266-via-android-using-telnet)

Here are the logs that Im getting on running my android code on connecting connect and send button.

```
01/18 20:02:32: Launching app
Cold swapped changes.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.manveenkaur.optimized/com.example.manveenkaur.optimized.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 9556 on device samsung-sm_e700h-268ada67
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.manveenkaur.optimized, real application class is null.
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
D/ViewRootImpl: Buffer Count from app info with  ::-1 && -1 for :: com.example.manveenkaur.optimized from View :: -1 DBQ Enabled ::false false
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (I716aebe4f9)
              OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
              Build Date: 07/01/15 수
              Local Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.031_02060873_02063264
              Remote Branch: 
              Local Patches: 
              Reconstruct Branch: 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 4096
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1e34142f time:924988396
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/ViewRootImpl: Buffer Count from app info with  ::-1 && -1 for :: com.example.manveenkaur.optimized from View :: -1 DBQ Enabled ::false false
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN`
```

**1.** I am unable to resolve this `ACTION_DOWN` statement

**2.** Also Id like to know what `Buffer Count from app info with  ::-1 && -1 for :: com.example.manveenkaur.optimized from View :: -1 DBQ Enabled ::false false means

**3.** Further on clicking disconnect it shows me the following :-

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.streamClosed(BufferedInputStream.java:125)
W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:257)
W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:98)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.io.input.TeeInputStream.read(TeeInputStream.java:127)
W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)
W/System.err:     at com.example.manveenkaur.optimized.PioneerController$1.run(PioneerController.java:41)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Also 
heres activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.manveenkaur.optimized.MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/message"
        android:inputType="text"></EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/send_button_text"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connectButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/connect_button_text"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/disconnectButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/disconnect_button_text"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One question upfront: Are you using SoftwareSerial or HardwareSerial to talk to the ESP8266? Using SoftwareSerial is not going to make you happy.

Comment: Im using HardwareSerial

Comment: What is the difference? Why is SoftwareSerial library worse?

Comment: Software Serial: You're pretty much guaranteed to loose some characters while your software is doing other things. HW serial uses a buffer that gets filled independently from what you are doing.